# Magento - Run Shell Script From Browser?

Tags: php, shell, magento

Point 6 on the below page describes how data can be imported using a script:
http://innoexts.com/currency-pricing/#.UjI1uPlgaHo

The problem is the example provides a shell script so I get an error when trying to run this from a browser.  Is there any way that these types of scripts can be run from as a browser as I don't have access to Shell?

Comment: it uses the shell to execute a php file. you should be able to trigger the execution of the file via a web-request as well. perhaps you need to adapt the parameter handling.

Comment: When I try from a browser I get an error: "This script cannot be run from Browser. This is the shell script." Apparently it is a security measure in Magento.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution to this.  Just needed to comment out the contents of protected function _validate() in /shell/abstract.php

Answer (score 1):

**In shell/abstract.php**
**add a line below**

```
protected $_factory; // Line 76
```

**as**

```
protected $_passvalidation = false;
```

Then change in function __construct()

```
$this->_validate();
```

**to**

```
if(!$this->_passvalidation) $this->_validate();
```

**In your shell script add**

```
function __construct() {
    $this->_passvalidation = true;
    parent::__construct();
}
```